# ArrayList of Possibly Many ArrayLists

Tags: java, oop, generics, arraylist

I want to be able to achieve some sort of class or variable that can store possibly many ArrayLists inside using Java.

For example, a two dimensional ArrayList would be like this: **ArrayList<ArrayList<Data_type>>**.

A three dimensional ArrayList is like this **ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Data_type>>>**.

And so on for any N sized ArrayList.

I want to implement a function that can take any N sized arraylist as a parameter, and I'm not quite so sure how to implement this and how the function signature would look like. I'm currently trying to use Generics which I have used in the past, but in this situation I'm a little lost.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Generics wouldn't work here, because the compiler would make no difference between `List<String>`, `List<List<String>>` or `List<List<List<String>>>`.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible but my best guess would be to use a pojo that has an array list of itself as well as the Data_type you intend and then you could nest it that way maybe? The inner pojo would have Data_type and no other properties, while all the rest would have the List of itself and no other properties.

Comment: @rainmaker Yeah I think your solution is correct all I wanted was a way to traverse in arraylist using some recursive method, my problem was knowing the function signature and how go about doing it inside the method when I make further nested calls, and creating it as well.

Comment: Consider treating the multi-dimensional lists as an implementation detail of a class that represents a flexibly sized multi-dimensional array, that can support any number of dimensions. Determine what methods you want your class to support. Implement those in terms of the multi-dimensional lists. Methods might refer to the whole array, a single element, or a slice of the array. Method parameters will depend on which of these the method is intended to access.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to create a `Container` class with either a wrapped value or a list with values:

```java
class Container<T> {
    private boolean isSingleElement;
    private T value;
    private List<Container<T>> list;
}
```

You could then add these constructors and static factory methods. They are able to create the containers.

```java
private Container(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.isSingleElement = true;
}

private Container(List<Container<T>> values) {
    this.list = Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
    this.isSingleElement = false;
}

public static <T> Container<T> ofSingle(T value) {
    return new Container<>(value);
}

public static <T> Container<T> ofList(List<T> list) {
    return new Container<>(list.stream()
        .map(Container::new)
        .toList());
}
```

You could then add methods to retrieve the information of what's in the container:

```java
public boolean isSingleElement() {
    return isSingleElement;
}

public T value() {
    if (!isSingleElement) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return value;
}

public List<Container<T>> list() {
    if (isSingleElement) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that the `list()` and `value()` methods both throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the container contains a single element or a list respectively. The disadvantage of this is that this causes to throw an error at runtime if the wrong method is called.

You could also remove the `value()` method altogether, and wrap a single element into a list, if you wish:

```java
public List<Container<T>> list() {
    if (isSingleElement) {
        return List.of(new Container<>(value));
    }
    else {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this time, You can create a loop and a recurssion while checking if the object obtained is a ArrayList, if it is a arrayList do a recursion again.. Here is a example

```java
// Suppose I've a ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>


/**
* @param ArrayList<?>
* Prints out all the values inside all the ArrayList present in the ArrayList
*/
public static void printArrayItems(ArrayList<?> a) {
    a.forEach((e) -> {
         if(e instanceof ArrayList) printArrayItems((ArrayList) e); else System.out.println(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the question mark indicate, does just mean that we don't know the type that ArrayList can have?

Comment: Yes, it means it can hold any type of Class object. It's a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Generics was added to have better type-safe code. But if you don't know the dimension, you can't create a type-safe N-dimensional structure using nested ArrayLists.

Perhaps you could use a flattened structure mapping coordinates to values.

```
Map<List<Integer>, DataType> twoDimensionalMap = Map.of(
    List.of(0,0), value00,
    List.of(0,1), value01,
    List.of(1,0), value10,
    List.of(1,1), value11
)
Map<List<Integer>, DataType> threeDimensionalMap = Map.of(
    List.of(0,0,0), value000,
    List.of(0,0,1), value001,
    List.of(0,1,0), value010,
    List.of(0,1,1), value011,
    ...
)
```

This is not completely type-safe, since there's no check that all coordinates are of the same length, or that all coordinates are filled in, but it's a workable solution to some usecases.